# SOQL query to get member data of members in a specific case team

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I want to get the Member information for the members of a Case Team. Is there anyway to do this without making multiple queries? It doesn't look like this data is associated with the record in the table `CaseTeamMember`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can do this (for some reason)

```
[select MemberId, Member.Name from CaseTeamMember where ParentId = '<Your Case Team Id`>]
```

I don't know if I'm missing something but this wasn't apparent from what I read in the documentation. I'm putting this here hoping it will help someone.